# COUNT and GROUP functions used in outer query and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query which involves creating sum figures and percentages of values (dumped to a single row) held on a single table. Each of the subqueries varies slightly with regard to the WHERE parameters. For example:

```
select distinct
count(KS2_PupilMatchingRefAnonymous) AS 'Total Pupils',

    (select count(KS2_PupilMatchingRefAnonymous) 
        from KS2_CandInd_2011 
        where KS2_MMSCH=1 
        and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1) AS 'All Eligible Pupils',
    (select count(*) 
        from KS2_CandInd_2011 
        where KS2_MMSCH=1 
        and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 
        and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 
        and FSMeligible=1) AS 'Eligible FSM only',  
    (select round(
    (cast((
        select count(*) 
            from KS2_CandInd_2011 
            where KS2_MMSCH=1 
            and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 
            and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 
            and FSMeligible=1) AS float) / 
    cast((
        select count(KS2_PupilMatchingRefAnonymous) 
            from KS2_CandInd_2011 
            where KS2_MMSCH=1 
            and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1) AS float))*100,2
             )) AS '% Eligible FSM'
from KS2_CandInd_2011
where KS2_MMSCH=1
```

I now want breakdown each subquery with a COUNT (and GROUP BY, of course) according to gender. If the COUNT/GROUP BY for gender is placed in the outer query, I only get a breakdown/split for the 'Total Pupils' value.

If I try to enter the same clauses in the subqueries I am told

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

The inner queries aren't really referencing the outer query, as per a correlated subquery, so im not really sure how to overcome the error despite my best attempts. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can re-write your query in much simpler way as shown below.(assuming you have a column called `gender` in your table: `KS2_CandInd_2011`

```
select 
a.gender
,count(*) AS 'Total Pupils',
,sum(case 
         when KS2_MMSCH=1 and  KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 then  1
       else 0
    end
    ) as  'All Eligible Pupils'
,sum(case
    when KS2_MMSCH=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and FSMeligible=1 then 1
      else 0
    end) as  'Eligible FSM only'
,round(cast( sum(case 
                    when KS2_MMSCH=1 and  KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 then  1
                  else 0
                end
            ) as float)/

cast(sum(case
    when KS2_MMSCH=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and FSMeligible=1 then 1
      else 0
    end)  as float)
        *100,2)  AS '% Eligible FSM'
from KS2_CandInd_2011 as a
where a.KS2_MMSCH=1
group by a.gender
order by a.gender;
```

The following is I believe will give you the exact output of your original query:

```
    select 
   ,count(*) AS 'Total Pupils',
    ,sum(case 
             when KS2_MMSCH=1 and  KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 then  1
           else 0
        end
        ) as  'All Eligible Pupils'
    ,sum(case
        when KS2_MMSCH=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and FSMeligible=1 then 1
          else 0
        end) as  'Eligible FSM only'
    ,round(cast( sum(case 
                        when KS2_MMSCH=1 and  KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 then  1
                      else 0
                    end
                ) as float)/

    cast(sum(case
        when KS2_MMSCH=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and KS2_ELIGENGTA=1 and FSMeligible=1 then 1
          else 0
        end)  as float)
            *100,2)  AS '% Eligible FSM'
    from KS2_CandInd_2011 as a
    where a.KS2_MMSCH=1
;
```

Comment: Yes! That works, although the percentage values came out a little off (558%!), but I can fix that. I guess the key was to use SUM rather than COUNT, then? Many thanks

Comment: Indeed! I use the above construct all the time when I have to count stuff but based on various conditions. If this solves your problem then you may accept it as a valid answer by clicking the tick icon.